# Get name value and put value to another name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of my several select options by name and take the one with a value (only one will have a value) then give the value to a name for the form.

So this is the form options, I'm leaving out all but the part with the name:

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="question_product_id" name="red"><option value="">Select a product</option>...
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="question_product_id" name="blue"><option value="">Select a product</option>
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="question_product_id" name="green"><option value="">Select a product</option>
```

The form looks for the value of this name, `question[product_id]` not green or red or blue. I am new to javascript and jquery. This is what I tried, but doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#red').val())
    {
        $('#question[product_id]').val() == $('#test').val()
    }
});
```

Is there a way to check the red blue and green selects for a value and if it does give it to question[product_id] for the server to grab?

So say for example out of the three selects I have the user selects a value in the one with name="red". The value can be "1".
Before the form submits I want to pass the value of "1" to another hidden non used select with the name "question[product_id]". So the select with the name question[product_id] would now have the value of "1" and the server would take it.

Comment: IDs must be unique and `#question[product_id]` probably doesn't do what you think it does. See http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/.

Comment: The name question[product_id] works fine. The server takes the value and all is well. But I need to have six divs so I need to name them different. That is why I am trying to set the value to this name.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Could you expand a little more?

Comment: If the name "red" has a value of 1 I want to give the name "question[product_id]" the value of 1.

Comment: You don't have an element with `id="red"`, neither an element with `id="test"` can't be found from your post. `#` finds `id`s, not `name`s.

Comment: @Teemu Well how do I get the script to get the names then?

Comment: Please re-read Felix Kling's comment, and follow the provided link.

Comment: I understand the id thing, but the server doesn't care about it. It only looks for the name value of question[product_id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you'll actually want to fire this on some event like a click or change, instead of on document ready like you're currently doing.

```
$('select').each(function(){
    if($(this).val())
    {
        $("[name='question[product_id]']").val($(this).val());
        return;
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xPL5z/)

Comment: It will take the first `select` element that has a value, and put that value into the element named `question[product_id]`.

Comment: Do I need to make a select with the name question[product_id] or will it just make and send it?

Comment: @DDDD In your update to your original question, you said that you wanted the value assigned to a hidden field. Obviously this would not just magically be created for you. See the demo that I added to my answer.

Comment: I see it, I am trying to implement it.

Comment: Is it possible to not get the first select value and get a specific one?

Comment: This works like a charm, +1 for dealing with me. Thanks a ton!